# I wrote a function for a math formula, may I ask you please check my code?

Tags: matlab

For my research, I needed to calculate some formula. I create a function for it. This is the very first time for me to write a function and also the first time to write a math formula in Matlab language. May I please ask you to check if where I do wrong?

Here is formula

[image]

And here is the function I wrote (P is x and P^ is y):

```
function biass = BIASS(x,y)
%This function calculates biass error
%   Detailed explanation goes here
H = sum(y-x)/sum(y)
biass = H * 100
end
```

I'm not sure about results because I believe they are not reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `y` is P^, then you should write `H = sum(y-x)/sum(x)`, not `H = sum(y-x)/sum(y)`.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly more efficient way to compute this is

```
100 * (sum(y) / sum(x) - 1)
```

since your expression can be simplified.